# Why my button is not under my div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a bug with my button. Like you can see on the screen the button is on my text and not under. If you have any idea... I really don't understand why.

[image]

```
.bouton-degrade {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e30613 0%, #95030FFF 80%);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
}

.bouton-degrade:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #e30613 0%, #95030F 80%);
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

margin-top: 1000px;

margin-bottom: -1000px;

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see, you didn't provide the HTML. [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry i forget pu screenshot

Comment: Now its good man

Comment: You have to show html file + i can't see this div class ( inside css). Button has nothing to do with its position. Try to use flexbox.

Comment: Without looking at the HTML code. All I can say is you can try adding non-breaking space (&nbsp) after the paragraphs.

Comment: The image is helpful, but it doesn't contain HTML. Please read: [This is what HTML looks like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics).

Comment: I can't post answer, but this is easy case, i can't see html too, but flexbox will help. Check what it is, and try this : .div{
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: column,
  gap: 10px
}

Comment: this question is impossible to answer.. you are missing to show how your parent container is positioning that button and how it's positioning the text underneath

Answer (score 1):

where you add the margin-bottom: -1000px remove it. `margin-bottom: -1000px`